# Can't update anaconda and python 3.6

Tags: macos, python-3.x, anaconda

I have Anaconda Python=2.7, and I try to install Anaconda Python 3.x 
but it says I just need to update the using conda update python=3.6

and I do this:

```
$conda update anaconda
```

but the result always:

> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: 'anaconda' Package 'anaconda' is not installed in /Users/MacBook/miniconda3

I successfully installed python 3.6 from python website, but when I check with:

```
$python --version
```

The result is `Python 2.7.12` and when I try:

```
$conda install python=3.6
```

or:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 ipykernel
```

the result is:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 None
for url <None>
The remote server could not find the channel you requested.
You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html>
```

The reason I am doing this is because I want to have an option for python version in Jupyter notebook.

but when I do

```
$ which -a python python=3.6
 /Users/MacBook/miniconda3/bin/python
 /Users/MacBook/miniconda2/bin/python
 /Users/MacBook/anaconda/bin/python
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python
```

I do same on my mac mini, and it works fine.

Have I messed up my python folder ?

Comment: check is conda installed by writing ' conda list '

Answer (score 0):

> I have Anaconda Python=2.7, and I try to install Anaconda Python 3.x but it says I just need to update the using conda update python=3.6
>
> and I do this:
>
> $conda update anaconda
>   but the result always:
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: 'anaconda' Package 'anaconda' is not installed in /Users/MacBook/miniconda3

This seems to me that your Anaconda (and thus Conda) wasn't properly installed. You should be able to download the Anaconda package and install it in one click. After that I would test if conda is working properly by running `conda list` and `conda search`.

> I successfully installed python 3.6 from python website, but when I check with:
>
> $python --version
>   The result is Python 2.7.12 and when I try:

The reason is most likely because python 3.6 is not in your PATH. Try `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `echo $PATH`.

> $conda install python=3.6
>   or:

If you wish to use only python 3.6, this is how you can install it.

> conda create -n py36 python=3.6 ipykernel
>   the result is:

if you wish to have both python 2 and 3, this is how you'd install python3. 
I would do `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda ipython`

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 None
>   for url 
>   The remote server could not find the channel you requested.
>   You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
>   Use `conda config --show` to view your configuration's current state.

Can you paste what you see after executing `conda config --show`?

do you see something like

```
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
pkgs/r: https://repo.continuum.io/
Users/admin/anaconda/conda-bld: file:///
pkgs/pro: https://repo.continuum.io/
pkgs/free: https://repo.continuum.io/
custom_multichannels:
local: ["file:///Users/admin/anaconda/conda-bld"]
defaults: ["https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free", 
"https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro"]
default_channels:
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro
```

> but when I do
>
> $ which -a python python=3.6
>    /Users/MacBook/miniconda3/bin/python
>   /Users/MacBook/miniconda2/bin/python
>   /Users/MacBook/anaconda/bin/python
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
>   /usr/local/bin/python
>   /usr/bin/python

look at you `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.